# Wrapping a paragraph around its content with line height < 1

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with paragraphs with big font size and line height smaller than the default, possibly even smaller than one. Trying to understand how it works.

In the snippet you'll see two paragraphs: the first with normal line height, the second with line height 0.8. 
We can see that the second paragraph is indeed shorter, but the top level span in it (red border) is taller than its containing paragraph. More interestingly, each line of text retains its height.
To demonstrate this, I wrapped just the first word in another span (green border). We can see that the inner span stays at exactly the same height. The outer span indeed becomes shorter, but only because the browser renders the top and the bottom lines on top of each other.

Another interesting fact is that the paragraph wraps around the text's baseline, so descenders will be cut off in the case of a paragraph with an overflow: hidden style.

Can someone explain this behaviour? Is there a way to cause the paragraph to wrap around the entire text, including ascenders/descenders?

Thanks. 
[image]

```js
$(function() {
  var $p1 = $('p:first'),
      $p2 = $('p:last'),
      $span1 = $p1.children().first(),
      $span1Inner = $span1.children().first(),
      $span2 = $p2.children().first(),
      $span2Inner = $span2.children().first();
   
  $p1.next().html("outer span height is: " 
               + $span1.outerHeight()
               + "<br>inner span height is: " 
               + $span1Inner.outerHeight()
               +"<br>p height is: " + $p1.outerHeight());
  $p2.next().html("outer span height is: " 
               + $span2.outerHeight()
               + "<br>inner span height is: " 
               + $span2Inner.outerHeight()
               +"<br>p height is: " + $p2.outerHeight());

});
```

```css
p {
  width: 270px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: black 1px solid;
}
p:last-of-type {
  line-height: 0.8;
}
p > span {
  border: red 1px solid
}
span > span {
  border: green 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p><span><span>HELLO</span> MR. JOE</span>
  </p>
  <div></div>
  <p><span><span>HELLO</span> MR. JOE joe</span>
  </p>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default display property of a **span** is **Inline**.
An inline element will accept margins, paddings and such that may also be visually caused by line-height changes. Although, the element still sits **inline** as you might expect.
 Margins and paddings will only push sibling or parent elements horizontally away, **not vertically**.
By attributing your child spans to display:inline-block, you'll be able to force the browser to respect the inner 's heights in order to auto-calculate the real height of the < p > element.

[image: Inline-block inner spans]

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: Thanks. Note that there are no paddings/margins at all here. What you suggest is the opposite - I meant for the paragraph to wrap around its content and not for the inner spans to shrink to the size of the paragraph (note that the j is still truncated). Also - the inner spans are there just for demonstration. The same thing will happen with no inner children at all.